# Protractor Tests run in parallel

Tags: protractor

I am new to Protractor and I am facing some problem when I tried to run multiple Protractor tests in parallel.

Here is my local.conf.ts file:

```
config.capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  args: [ 'lang=en-US' ],
  shardTestFiles: true,
  maxInstances: 8,
  prefs: {
    intl: { accept_languages: "en-US" },
  },
  'goog:chromeOptions': {
    w3c: false
  }
}
```

1. By multi-instances mode, some click(); functions seemed to have influences on other chrome browsers.
2. And I also found that some "modal-dialog" on one browser, will display on other browsers as well. (I am sure that this will not happen by single browser instance mode)

has someone else also these similar issues?

Comment: It sounds really application-specific and might just be the symptom of how your application under test treats multiple session per single user.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to reproduce the problem manually and see if it is possible to test it in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be a good next step. It could just be some set of tests could not run in parallel because of how application works. If that's the case, you'd have a few options - one being using multiple accounts, organizing into suites etc.

Comment: the single user will create different, independent test projects, the projects should be 100% independent of each other. I am quite confused but thank you for your help

Comment: I will try to use multiple users.

Comment: @alecxe Hi do you think "browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform()" might have an impact on other browsers?

Comment: No this would only be executed in the context of one browser.

Answer (score 1):

We have achieved parallel execution using multicapabilities in chrome. May be this helps you out.

We updated config.js as below :

```
 multiCapabilities: [{
    'name': 'test1',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    specs: ['feature 1', 'feature 2'],
  }, {
    'name': 'test2',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    specs: ['feature 3', 'feature 4'],
  },
```

Cheers!